# Predict particular value from linear-log (semi-log) regression model using R

Tags: r, predictive-models, linear-model, lm

I'm having difficulties to properly predict a particular value from a linear regression model with log-transformed x (independent) variable using R.

I have a data set that contains measurements of y (water depth) and x (percent of surface (maximum) irradiance) that show a linear relationship when x is log-transformed.

I manage to fit a linear model using `stats::lm` but when using `ggplot` to visually inspect my calculated value for the water depths where only 0.01 (1%) of the surface (maximum) light remains, I realize that my prediction is off (see my reproducible example below).

I assume that this is because my calculation of the water depth where only 1% of the surface light remains by only using a single coeffient (`my.lm$coefficients[2]`) is oversimplified, ignoring the intercept and error term?!

I already went through similar questions that somewhat got close to my problem (e.g. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/08/forecasting-from-log-linear-regressions/; https://bookdown.org/ccolonescu/RPoE4/prediction-r-squared-and-modeling.html).
Yet, I'm currently feeling stuck and didn't manage to achieve a mathematically sound solution.

Ideally, I would prefer a solution based on base R.

Many thanks in advance for any help and suggestions!

A `reprex` using a real world example representing my data is:

```r
library(tidyverse)

## the example data can be downloaded from
# https://github.com/janstrauss1/oceanographic_data_analysis/blob/324e9151e9017d17b1a5f9770f33b0999616c453/underwater_irradiance_data.csv
# underwater_irradiance_data <- read.table(file = "underwater_irradiance_data.csv")

## download directly from github
underwater_irradiance_data <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/janstrauss1/oceanographic_data_analysis/master/underwater_irradiance_data.csv")

## fit a liner model to the logarithmic light irradiance (percent_max_PAR) data 
## calculated as percent_max_PAR = max(PAR, na.rm = TRUE)
my.lm <- lm(log(underwater_irradiance_data$percent_max_PAR) ~ underwater_irradiance_data$depth)
summary(my.lm)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = log(underwater_irradiance_data$percent_max_PAR) ~ 
#>     underwater_irradiance_data$depth)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -0.13343 -0.06680 -0.02271  0.04074  0.57870 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)                      -0.4318569  0.0140668   -30.7   <2e-16 ***
#> underwater_irradiance_data$depth -0.0590871  0.0002134  -276.9   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.1019 on 221 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9971, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9971 
#> F-statistic: 7.668e+04 on 1 and 221 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

# then calculate the depth where 0.01 (1%) light is left
z_light <- log(0.01) / my.lm$coefficients[2]
z_light
#> underwater_irradiance_data$depth 
#>                         77.93865

# plotting and visual inspection shows that calculated value does not match
ggplot(data = underwater_irradiance_data,
       mapping = aes(x = percent_max_PAR, y = depth)) +
geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 0.01, y = z_light), color = "red") +
geom_vline(xintercept = 0.01, lty = "dashed") +
geom_hline(yintercept = as.numeric(z_light[1]), lty = "dashed") +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE) +
scale_y_reverse(limit = c(80,0), expand = c(0,0)) +
scale_x_log10(limit = c(0.001,1), position = "top", expand = c(0,0)) +
labs(y = "Depth [m]", x = "Quantum irradiance [E\u2080, % of surface PAR]") +
theme(text = element_text(family = "sans"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The linear model assumes constant surface light and constant depth-independent extinction coefficient. However, we see that your data are not log-linear at the surface, so there was either a drift of the surface light (cloudy sky) or a horizon with higher extinction at the surface, e.g. as a result of plankton. In such a case, one may consider to estimate the 1% depth directly from the data.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @tpetzold! I'm aware that there are probably some limitations in the given data set. Yet, beyond a discipline-specific discussion, I'd be additionally very much interested in a general, statistically sound, solution to the given problem of making predictions based on a linear-log (semi-log) regression model or an alternative solution to the given problem.
You are suggesting to estimate the 1% depth directly from the data but could you specify how, based on the given example? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try a smoother, gam, for example.